# how to Get kernel debug messages

Tags: kernel, debugging

I have installed the kernel debug symbols for my system

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.11.0-17-generic-dbgsym
```

Also

```
$ sysctl kernel.printk
kernel.printk = 7   4   1   7
```

But when typing

```
sudo dmesg -wH
```

I get just real error messages. I do not get any debug info.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the debug symbols, which are not related to debug messages.

With the debug symbols you can use debuggers, like gdb.

In order to read debug messages you need to compile the kernel/kernel module with the DEBUG define.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it. I have a program that interact with the kernel. There is a freeze at the kernel level. I'd like to know what causing it. I did not get enough enough info from  dmesg and from journalctl.

Comment: If it fully freezes like a thunder, it doesn't matter, nothing will catch it because, well, it crashed that bad.

Comment: Most kernel failures, "oops", and panics, will still reach the console or even log into journalctl, but some won't. The best option is to get netconsole up and running and capture the logs in real time from another computer. With the DEBUG messages you will only get the messages marked for debug. It may give you hints of what went bad, but not likely. The error/panic/oops messages come always, you dont need a DEBUG kernel.